# Asynchronous NetworkStream continuous reading design pattern

Tags: c#, asynchronous, networkstream

I'm trying to convert a class which uses multiple threads to use overlapping I/O.  It's almost working, but it seems to randomly hit a threading issue, and I'm not sure why.

Too much code to post directly, but here's the basic pattern.  The goal is to sit there reading data off the connection until the connection get disposed, so when each `EndRead()` completes, it should start a new `BeginRead()`.

```
public enum State
{
    Idle,
    BeforeRead,
    PendingRead,
    FinishingRead,
    Died,
}

private int state;
private IAsyncResult asyncResult;
private byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
private System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream stream;
public void Connect(System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client, string host, int port)
{
    client.Connect(host, port);
    this.stream = client.GetStream();
}

private bool SetState(State expectedState, State newState)
{
    return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.state, (int)newState, (int)expectedState) == expectedState;
}
public void BeginRead()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!SetState(State.Idle, State.BeforeRead))
                return;
            IAsyncResult async;
            async = stream.BeginRead(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length, x => EndRead(true), null);
            if (async == null)
                return;
            SetState(State.BeforeRead, State.PendingRead);
            lock (this)
                this.asyncResult = async;
            if (async.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(0))
                EndRead(false);
        }
    }
    catch { this.state = State.Died; }
}
private void EndRead(bool asynchronousCallback)
{
    try
    {
        if (!SetState(State.PendingRead, State.FinishingRead))
            return;
        IAsyncResult async;
        lock (this)
        {
            async = this.asyncResult;
            this.asyncResult = null;
        }
        if (async == null)
            return;
        int bytesRead = stream.EndRead(async);
        HandleData(bytesRead, readBuffer);
        SetState(State.FinishingRead, State.Idle);
        if (asynchronousCallback)
            BeginRead();
    }
    catch { this.state = State.Died; }
}
```

Most of the time it works, but occasionally it does one of several things:

- Stops receiving messages
- Throws an exception that I the `asyncResult has already been handled: "EndReceive can only be called once for each asynchronous operation"`.

I should also mention that there is synchronous writing going on from another thread (stream.Write, not `stream.BeginWrite`).  I think reading and writing should be independent of each other, so it shouldn't affect the behavior.

Is my design fundamentally flawed?  This is a stripped down example, so it's possible the stuff I stripped out could be causing the problem, but I need to know if my basic design is valid or not.  What is the proper way to chain read asynchronously?

(And in case the suggestion is to use `async/await`, this code needs to run on Windows XP, so that's not an option.)

Comment: Could you please include the data type for your "stream" variable.

Comment: It's a System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream (although in my live code, it could be either that or a NegotiateStream, depending on the situation).

Comment: I use Begin/End pattern long time ago, but I remember that there were strange issue like, that IAsyncResult return from `BeginRead` might not be same as the one provided in `AsyncCallback`. Call `EndRead` on the instance from `AsyncCallback` (that is the `x` you don't use).
In addition your state management using `SetState` seems wrong. Async callback can be called before your `SetState`.
Also what is point of doing async I/O and then waiting in infinite loop? Just continue your read from async callback.

Comment: @Honza The point of using an infinite loop is that if there's more data ready than is in the buffer, it might recursively bounce back and forth between StartRead and EndRead until it gets a stack overflow.  EndRead only calls back into StartRead it wasn't called from StartRead itself.

Comment: Did you actually get the stack overflow? I suspect that you creating recursion your self by calling `if (async.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(0)) EndRead(false);` which if called from `EndRead`....

Comment: @Honza I have not experienced a stack overflow from this, but it would be possible if data is coming in faster than it can be processed.  That "false" argument is there to prevent recursion.  If it finishes synchronously, the while loop should allow it to iterate to the next chunk of data.  If it finishes asynchronously, EndRead should fire off the next BeginRead itself.

Comment: Async call back will be called for synchronous execution too, so you might have to EndRead for one operation.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx

Comment: @Honza Yes, the SetState guard should only allow one of the calls to EndRead to succeed, that's the main reason it's there.  Making it only use the async callback seems to have fixed the issues I'm actually having, so I guess worrying about theoretical stack overflows is probably lower priority than generally broken code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a race condition:

```
        IAsyncResult async;
        async = stream.BeginRead(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length, x => EndRead(true), null);

        /* Race condition here */   

        if (async == null)
            return;
        SetState(State.BeforeRead, State.PendingRead);
        lock (this)
            this.asyncResult = async;
```

Your `EndRead` can execute before the `SetState` and/or before the `this.asyncResult = async` executes. You cannot do this. The state must be set *before* the `BeginRead` is issued, and reset in case of failure. Do not retain and use a member `asyncResult`, but instead pass the callback to `BeginRead` and get the async result on the callback:

```
  SetState(State.BeforeRead, State.PendingRead);
  stream.BeginRead(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length, EndRead);

 ...

  private void EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) {
     int bytesRead = stream.EndRead(asyncResult);
     ...
  }
```

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to @Honza, I'm worried if EndRead occurs synchronously from the call to BeginRead, and it then triggers the next BeginRead, they could end up recursing into a stack overflow.  How do I prevent that scenario if I can't use the return value of BeginRead?